# Understanding Haskell's `toUpper`

Tags: haskell, toupper

Looking at the Haskell source for [toUpper](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Unicode.html#toUpper):

```
toUpper c = chr (fromIntegral (towupper (fromIntegral (ord c))))  
... 
foreign import ccall unsafe "u_towupper"
  towupper :: CInt -> CInt
```

What is the meaning of `chr`, as well as `u_towupper`? I'm curious about the `foreign import ccall unsafe` part too. Does the Haskell source actually mutate, hence the `unsafe`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First `ord` converts a `Char` to an `Int`, then `fromIntegral` converts it to `CInt`. On the other side `fromIntegral` converts a `CInt` to an `Int`, then `chr` converts the `Int` to a `Char`.

An `unsafe` foreign import means that the C function `u_towupper` does not call back into haskell. If Ghc knows this, then it can make some optimizations. It has nothing to do with mutation.